# Проблема с доступом к external storage Android

Tags: android, файловая-система

Требуется  вывести все файлы и директории внутри определенной директории. Сначала имеем доступ к "/" телефона, затем при попытке открытия и получения всех директорий из директорий "/sdcard/" методом file.list() возвращается null, хотя файлы в папке есть. Помимо "/sdcard/", которая является external storage (памятью телефона), null возвращается также при доступе к карте памяти (в моем случае она лежит в "/storage/". В манифесте прописано разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Чувак, у него 8 классов в программе, тебе какой?